# Calling javascript function using python function in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have a website built using the django framework that takes in an input csv folder to do some data processing. I would like to use a html text box as a console log to let the users know that the data processing is underway. The data processing is done using a python function. It is possible for me to change/add text inputs into the text box at certain intervals using my python function?

Sorry if i am not specific enough with my question, still learning how to use these tools!

Edit - Thanks for all the help though, but I am still quite new at this and there are lots of things that I do not really understand. Here is an example of my python function, not sure if it helps

```
def query_result(request, job_id):
info_dict = request.session['info_dict']
machines = lt.trace_machine(inputFile.LOT.tolist())
return render(request, 'tools/result.html', {'dict': json.dumps(info_dict),
                                             'job_id': job_id})
```

Actually my main objective is to let the user know that the data processing has started and that the site is working. I was thinking maybe I could display an output log in a html textbox to achieve this purpose.

Comment: Not getting what you want to achieve, do you want to show the status of processing to user on definite intervals?

Comment: Django doesn't provide you that ability. You need to implement it yourself. Such functionality is implemented if other technologies like JSF. I guess if you google for a while you will probably find some middleware that handles this for you.

Answer (score 0):

While it is impossible for the server (Django) to directly update the client (browser), you can you JavaScript to make the request, and Django can return a [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse). As each part of the response is received, you can update the textbox using JavaScript.

Here is a sample with pseudo code

```
def process_csv_request(request):
    csv_file = get_csv_file(requests)
    return StreamingHttpResponse(process_file(csv_file))

def process_file(csv_file):
    for row in csv_file:
         yield progress
         actual_processing(row)
    return "Done"
```

Alternatively you could write the process to the db or some cache, and call an API that returns the progress repeatedly from the frontend

Answer (score 0):

No cannot do that because you already at server side therefor you cannot touch anything in html page.

You can have 2 ways to do that:

1. You can make a interval function to call to server and ask the progress and update the progress like you want at callback function.
2. You can open a socket connection in your server & browser to instantly update.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with websockets using [Django Channels](https://github.com/django/channels).

Here's a sample consumer:

```
class Consumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.group_name = self.scope['user']
        print(self.group_name)  # use this for debugging not sure what the scope returns

        # Join group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    def update_html(self, event):
        status = event['status']
        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'status': status
        }))
```

Running through the Channels 2.0 tutorial you will learn that by putting some javascript on your page, each time it loads it will connect you to a websocket consumer. On `connect()` the consumer adds the user to a group. This group name is used by your csv processing function to send a message to the browser of any users connected to that group (in this case just one user) and update the html on your page.

```
def send_update(channel_layer, group_name, message):
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        group_name,
        {
            'type': 'update_html',
            'status': message
        }
    )

def process_csv(file):
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    group_name = get_user_name()  # function to get same group name as in connect()
    with open(file) as f:
        reader=csv.reader(f)
        send_update(channel_layer, group_name, 'Opened file')
        for row in reader:
            send_update(channel_layer, group_name, 'Processing Row#: %s' % row)
```

You would include javascript on your page as outlined in the Channels documentation then have an extra `onmessage` function fro updating the html:

```
var WebSocket = new ReconnectiongWebSocket(...);

WebSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    $('#htmlToReplace').html(data['status']);
}
```